# Unable to distribute archive after Adding AudioKit v5 as Swift Package

Tags: ios, xcode, audiokit

When archiving my app using AudioKit v5 as Swift Package, I cant distribute it.
I see no version and identifier in the archive detail view.
Also there is no armv7 architecture, maybe it is related.
see attached images.
Any idea?

Comment: There exists an AUdioKit issue for this as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated! https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/2279

Comment: I have submitted a technical support request to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed and will available in a few minutes.